# Toggle bit value in database with buttons - Using Entity Framework

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4

I have an html table that holds categories of things. Each row consists of a category id and name that are looped in from the model. There are also two buttons in each row. One that I want to use to set the state of the row to enabled and the other to set it to disabled:

http://codepen.io/cavanflynn/pen/waPXww - This codepen shows how I'm working the buttons on the front end

```
<table id="categoryList" class="table">
    <thead>
    <tr>
        <th>Category ID</th>
        <th>Category Name</th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    @foreach (var item in Model.Categories)
    {
        <tr>
            <td>@item.id</td>
            <td>@item.name</td>
            <td>
                <button class="btn btn-success categoryEnabled">Enabled</button>
                <button class="btn btn-danger categoryDisabled" style="display: none;">Disabled</button>
            </td>
        </tr>
    }
    </tbody>
</table>
```

When I say set to enabled or disabled I mean change the bit value for that row in an SQL table column called state. So, I basically just need the buttons to toggle that bit value for the row in which it is clicked. I have been struggling to figure out the method to do this.

Example controller code to help out:

```
    public ActionResult SaveCategory(int categoryId, String categoryName)
    {
        var connection = new CategoryDBEntities();

        if (categoryId > 0)
        {
            var rsc = connection.QualityCategories.Find(categoryId);
            rsc.name = categoryName;
        }
        else
        {
            QualityCategory rsc = new QualityCategory();
            rsc.name = categoryName;
            connection.QualityCategories.Add(rsc);
        }

        connection.SaveChanges();
        return Redirect(System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request.UrlReferrer.AbsolutePath);
    }
```

(This code is used to save category changes)

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Do you want a postback or AJAX? Do you have some example controller code?

Comment: AJAX would be best, but I am just trying to figure out a method to do this either way. I'll update with some example controller code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming your `Category` object looks something like:

```
public enum StatesTypes
{
    Disabled = 0,
    Enabled = 1
}

public class Category
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public StatesTypes State { get; set; }

    public String Name { get; set; }
}
```

Perhaps then you could have a `SaveCategory` method within your `Controller` which returns back a `Json` object.

```
public JsonResult SaveCategory(StatesTypes state, int categoryId)
{
    CategoryJsonViewModel ret = new CategoryJsonViewModel();

    ret.Response = //Use EF here - perhaps call a service object to save the category?

    if(ret.Response == BaseJsonResponseTypes.Success)
    {
        if(state == StatesTypes.Disabled)
        {
            ret.Message = "Category successfully disabled";
        }
        else
        {
            ret.Message = "Category successfully enabled";
        }
    }
    else
    {
        ret.Message = "Critical error :-(";
    }

    return Json(ret);
}
```

Dependency classes (up to you how you do this):

```
public enum BaseJsonResponseTypes
{
    NotSet = 0,
    Error = 1,
    Success = 2
}

public class BaseJsonViewModel
{
    public BaseJsonResponseTypes Response { get; set; }

    public String Message { get; set; }
}

public class CategoryJsonViewModel : BaseJsonViewModel
{
    //Maybe you could include some implemention here.
}
```

Your jQuery would look something like:

```
$(".disable").on("click", function(){
  $(this).hide();
  $(this).next().show();
  var id = $(this).data('val');
  SaveCategory(0, id);
});

$(".enable").on("click", function(){
  $(this).hide();
  $(this).prev().show();
  var id = $(this).data('val');
  SaveCategory(1, id);
});

function SaveCategory(state, id) {

  var obj = {
      state: state,
      categoryId: id
  };

  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "/category/savecategory",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    data : JSON.stringify(obj),
    dataType: "json",
    success: function(data) {
      //Do something cool with the data object?
      alert(data.Message);
    }
  });
}
```

`data-val` attribute has been added, as shown (this passes through the category id):

`<button class="disable" data-val="@item.id">Disable</button>
<button class="enable" style="display:none;" data-val="@item.id">Enable</button>`

Answer (score 1):

You need to give your buttons some way to pass the specific row identifier to the back-end, so that it knows which row to effect.

```
<button class="disable" id="Row1Disable">Disable</button>
```

Then you will need to hook up your jquery post method to your controller action, something something like this:

```
$(".disable").on("click", function(){
$(this).hide();
$(this).next().show();

$.post("@Url.Action("DisableRow", "MyController")", { "Id": $(this).attr('id') }, function (response) {
   if (response.success) {
      // Handle successful disabled post.
      alert('Row Disabled!');
    } else {
      // Handle error.
      alert('Error disabling row!');
    }
  });
});

$(".enable").on("click", function(){
  $(this).hide();
  $(this).prev().show();

  $.post("@Url.Action("EnableRow", "MyController")", { "Id": $(this).attr('id') }, function (response) {
    if (response.success) {
      // Handle successful disabled post.
      alert('Row Enabled!');
    } else {
      // Handle error.
      alert('Error enabling row!');
    }
  });
});
```

Once the posts are hooked up to proper controller actions, you should be good to go.  Here's the codePen based on your original one: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/xGPzZW?editors=101

---

Edit exemplifying ID uniqueness in loop:

using for loop:

```
for(int i = 0; i < rows.Count(); i++)
{
  string id = "Row" + i.ToString() + "Enable";
  // do the rest...
}
```

using while / foreach loop:

```
int i = 0;

foreach (var row in Model.Rows)
{
  string id = "Row" + i.ToString() + "Enable";
  i +=1;
  // do the rest...
}
```

Comment: Great! Thank you! My only question is if I'm looping the buttons into the row then how cold I pass the specific row identifier in (since I couldn't give each one an id)?

Comment: If you're using a for loop, you can just use the indexer to help create the id, otherwise you can create and increment your own indexer and use it similarly.  Something like: string id = "Row" + i.ToString() + "Enable";